# No such file or directory error tensorflow custom object detection

Tags: python, tensorflow, python-3.6

Getting an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "generate_tfrecord.py", line 97, in <module>
    tf.app.run()
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\platform\app.py", line 124, in run
    _sys.exit(main(argv))
  File "generate_tfrecord.py", line 88, in main
    tf_example = create_tf_example(group, path)
  File "generate_tfrecord.py", line 43, in create_tf_example
    encoded_jpg = fid.read()
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\lib\io\file_io.py", line 119, in read
    self._preread_check()
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\lib\io\file_io.py", line 79, in _preread_check
    compat.as_bytes(self.__name), 1024 * 512, status)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\errors_impl.py", line 473, in __exit__
    c_api.TF_GetCode(self.status.status))
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError: NewRandomAccessFile failed to Create/Open: D:\Custom-Object-Detection-master\images\1 : The system cannot find the file specified.
; No such file or directory
```

Cloned this repository:

https://github.com/bourdakos1/Custom-Object-Detection

all runnning fine with those files, but when I create my own dataset with labelimg and own images, it wont work, all the files are in exact same places, same names etc. but cant get it to work, any advice?

win 10, tensorflow 1.5

Comment: Does the folder `D:\Custom-Object-Detection-master\images\` exist?

Comment: yes, all the folders and files exist, just replaced the images and xml's with my own

Answer (score 2):

If someone is having the same problem, labelimg somehow made the xml's like:

```
<annotation>
  <folder>train</folder>
  <filename>1</filename>
  <path>1.jpg</path>
  <source>
    <database>Unknown</database>
  </source>
  <size>
    <width>106</width>
    <height>107</height>
    <depth>3</depth>
  </size>
  <segmented>0</segmented>
  <object>
    <name>bat</name>
    <pose>Unspecified</pose>
    <truncated>0</truncated>
    <difficult>0</difficult>
    <bndbox>
      <xmin>25</xmin>
      <ymin>30</ymin>
      <xmax>73</xmax>
      <ymax>82</ymax>
    </bndbox>
  </object>
</annotation>
```

where the filename should be 1.jpg and not 1, this solved the problem. :)